# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime in Biztalk Mapping

Tags: c#, biztalk, biztalk-mapper

We have the following code in LINQPad 5 which compiles and gives the expected output:

```
void Main(){
Console.WriteLine(thissucks("Sometext. IfCondition: 20180125.")); }


public string thissucks(string inputString){

    string[] words = inputString.Split(':');
    string date = words.GetValue(1).ToString();
    string comment = words.GetValue(0).ToString();
    date = date.Replace(".","");
    date = date.Trim();

    if (inputString.Contains("IfCondition"))
    {
        DateTime formatDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date,"yyyyMMdd", null);
        return comment + ": " + formatDate.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") + ".";
    }
    else
    {
        return inputString;
    }
```

}

This produces the output: `Sometext. IfCondition: 25.01.2018`

However, when we put it into our script functoid in the biztalk map, we get the error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

Comment: Are you *sure* this is the code and input that throws, not something else? What is the *full* exception string, including the call stack? Passing `null` as a CultureInfo doesn't mean `don't use a CultureInfo` btw. It means use the current one.

Comment: You don't need to use `GetValue` with an array or `ToString()` with a string. Is this the actual code that throws or was this translated from Visual Basic?

Comment: This is copied from LINQPad, and the thissucks mehtod is what is used in the script functoid in biztalk mapper. It works fine in LINQPad, but shows "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." in Biztalk when testing the map. This is the only error it shows. I am not sure where I can find call stack in biztalk?

Comment: For what input? What happens if `SomeText` contains `:` ?

Comment: For the input used as parameter in the main. Sometext will never contain : when IfCondition is met, but may sometimes when IfCondition is not met. Might this still be a problem?

Comment: Something tells me that there *is* a `:` in there, resulting in a matching `Contains` and an invalid date string. What input did you use to test the functoid?

Comment: Ok! I shall investigate this further. Thank you so much for the reply. Here's the input: `09Utløpsdato/siste forfallsdato: 20180125`. Then later there comes a line which contains a `:` but does not meet the IfCondition.

Comment: Input was the problem, thank you so much! I got a little blind on my own sollution from staring at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Panagiotis suggested the input line in the file made this error, and inputed `:` following a string that was not a valid DateTime.